# "Crop-like" visual effect around the headings

Tags: html, css

I was assigned an interesting task and it seems like a nice entry point to this wonderful community, so here I am, hello.

What I am required to do is to create "crop-like" (so they said, not-exact for me, but whatever) effect around headings, basically a CSS class `.croplike-effect` which will make those heading look roughly like this:

[image: <code>.croplike-effect</code>]

It is just a mockup photo, but I am sure you get the idea.

I messed around with `:before` and `:after` CSS elements, some borders and `transform: rotate` but with nothing worth sharing here, really. I am stuck.

```css
.croplike-effect {
  border: 2px solid #C6C6C6;
  color: #5E5E67;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="croplike-effect">My heading</h1>
```

Ideally, it will not require additional elements in the HTML markup, I hope it is doable.

Thank you :).

Comment: where is the mock of crop like?

Comment: I could not add a photo as it is my first question, it is behind the link `.croplike-effect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea with only background:

```css
.croplike-effect {
  color: #5E5E67;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent calc(50% - 1px),#C6C6C6 calc(50% - 1px),#C6C6C6 calc(50% + 1px),transparent 0) 28px 0/ calc(148% - 54px) calc(133% - 54px) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#C6C6C6,#C6C6C6) 25px calc(100% - 25px)/calc(100% - 26px) 2px  no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#C6C6C6,#C6C6C6) 0 25px/calc(100% - 26px) 2px  no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#C6C6C6,#C6C6C6) calc(100% - 25px) 26px/2px calc(100% - 26px) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#C6C6C6,#C6C6C6) 25px 0/2px calc(100% - 26px) no-repeat, 
    linear-gradient(#F2F2F2,#F2F2F2) center/calc(100% - 54px) calc(100% - 54px) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="croplike-effect">My heading</h1>
<h1 class="croplike-effect">My other heading</h1>
<h1 class="croplike-effect">heading</h1>
```

Comment: Very cool, just tell me why it does not really look like 30px padding to me? :)

Comment: @DKSTNR add border and you will understand ;) .. it's because I have played with background and the background is not covering the whole area

Comment: OK, I checked with jsfiddle. How would I create an empty space between the border created with the `linear-gradient` and the text?

Comment: Inside the `calc()`, hardcoded, right? Is it doable?

Comment: @DKSTNR yes, each gradient has a position (the first two number) then a size (the 2 number after the /) so simply play with values and you will see the result ;)

Comment: Awesome, you are rockstar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> New Edit: Added an extra `span` to do the job which is against requirement as it cant be done with
>   single element.

You can try with after/before pseudo class. Its not perfect but enough to tweak.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


  .croplike-effect {
    border: 2px solid #C6C6C6;
    color: #5E5E67;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }


  .croplike-effect:before{
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: -32px;
     left: -32px;
     border: 2px solid #C6C6C6;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     border-top: 0;
     border-left: 0;
  }

  .croplike-effect:after{
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -32px;
     right: -32px;
     border: 2px solid #C6C6C6;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     border-bottom: 0;
     border-right: 0;
  }

  .diagonal-line{
     position: absolute;
     top: 26px;
     right: -51px;
     width: 134%;
     height: 2px;
     background-color: #C6C6C6;
     transform: rotate(-202.5deg);
     z-index: -1;
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="croplike-effect">My heading <span class="diagonal-line"></span></h1>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us7ytnpL/18/) for it

Comment: It's missing the diagonal.

Comment: Updated !!  UI wise it's little odd to see diagonal line crossing in a weird way so have kept it what it should look good.

Comment: Diagonal does not come out of the angle point directly, how to fix it?

Comment: @DKSTNR It's updated but needed to add an extra span to do the job as it can't be done.

Comment: Technically, it still isn't the diagonal, it's not accurate enough. Thanks for your tryouts, it points me to some direction, but is not enough to accept as an answer.